# Google Apps Business gmail stop logoff and popham SMS verification

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, google-workspace

I work in company 400people, we use Gmail for Business. We not given password to mail for our employers for secure reasons. Hard drivers are encrypted so they need only one password to log in.

But i had to every day log in into Gmail about ~30 people, because [session,cookie] expire. Its really annoying and everytime ask about tel number and sms verification. For every user i have do this one two times for month.

Maybe its some immortal cookie session in Chrome or some hidden options in Gmail Business ? Also maybe some options to disable notification about add tel number for 2 way authorization don;t needed this.

Please help me

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but are you asking if there is some magic way to circumvent the two-factor authentication? It would kind of defeat the purpose of two-factor wouldn't it?

Comment: Some magic way to disable notification for two-factor notification, we will never use this. And some options to stop Gmail log off after eq 1 month.